# Javascript not being executed

Tags: javascript, php, redirect

This is the top of my php file - what I am trying to achieve is, if the user ends up on this page after a failed login attempt which posts here - a message should be displayed in javascript outlining such failed login attempt and then redirect them back to the previous page.

Why does this happen and what can be done to fix it so the message box is displayed? Alternatively on the previous page - how do i stop the redirect if the login attempt failed?

Thanks

```
<?php

include("Application.php");
include("Member.php");
include("ContactDetails.php");
include("LoginDetails.php");

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}

$value = null;
if(isset($_SESSION['url'])) {
    $value = $_SESSION['url'];
    $_SESSION['url'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=$_POST["username"];
    $password=$_POST["password"];
    $loginDetails = logUserIn($username, $password);
    if($loginDetails != null && $loginDetails->getUserid() > 0){
        $contactDetails = getContactDetails($loginDetails->getUserid());
        $member = new Member($contactDetails, $loginDetails);
        //an array of applications belong to a paticular user
        $applications = getApplicationsForMember($member);
        printUserApplicationSelectionForm($applications);
    }else{
        //login attempt failed - tell the user and redirect
        if($value != null){
            $path = "http://localhost" . "$value";
            header("Location: $path");
            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Login Attempt Failed!");</script>'; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That happens because you redirect and show message both. Use js redirect, without `header`. `<script>setTimeout(function(){location.href='http://localhost/url';},5000);</script>`

Comment: Your first paragraph explained what you're trying to achieve, then your next paragraph asks, _"why does this happen?"_  Why does what happen?  You don't seem to have mentioned the problem.  Please be more clear about what is happening.

Comment: Also you can use js `confirm` to redirect by button click.

Answer (score 0):

You change locations before echoing, so the alert script is never echoed:

```
        header("Location: $path");
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Login Attempt Failed!");
```

Switch those around and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

if you send the location header, the browser won't load the response (your script) anymore from the current page but directly change to to the new location.
What you could do is to add something like `&message=failedlogin` to the path before sending the Location header and then display a message in the previous page. You could also store it in the session: 
`$_SESSION['loginsuccess']=false;` and then check for this value in the previous PHP page.